# Display a message when no results are returned from an exposed filter

Tags: views, search

How do I add a message, or change the view's behaviour when there is no result returned from a view's exposed filter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you edit your view (D7), under 'Advanced' you will find an item labelled 'No Results Behavior' which gives you a selection of options. The usual is to select 'Global Text Area' and return a no results found message.